# flutter List view with cards

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner in Flutter programming, and I am in the learning phase. I am trying to create only the UI of a list using dummy data for the item which can be bought very frequently by the customer. for example a customer has bought pencils very often, and a pen not so often, so the pencils will be on the top of the list and pen will be below the pencils and so on...! Below is the image which I wanted to create
waiting for your suggestions. thanks

in short frequently bought items are on the top of the list.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, @Fahmida for your response.
I am trying to create a listview with different products using dummy data, and the purpose is if the item is frequently bought by the customer then it will be on the top of the list. Later on this list will come from backend

Comment: If i change the frequency of product in the dummy data then that product will go up/down based on the frequency value

Answer (score 0):

```
     List dataItems = [
    {"product": "pencil", "frequency" :4},
      {"product": "pencil2", "frequency" :4},
      {"product": "pencil4", "frequency" :4}
  ];


 Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                 Row(children: const[
                   Text("No"),
                   SizedBox(width: 16),
                   Text("Product"),
                    SizedBox(width: 16),
                   Text("Frequency"),
                  
                 ]),
                Expanded(
                child:      ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 2,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index){
                  return       Row(children: [
                   Text(index.toString()),
                     SizedBox(width: 16),
                   Text(dataItems[index]["product"]),
                     SizedBox(width: 16),
                    Text(dataItems[index]["frequency"].toString()),
                    
                    Spacer(),
                    
                     MaterialButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("Deliver"), ),
                    MaterialButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text("Self Pickup"), )
                   
                 ]);
                }
                  
                ))
              ],
            ),
```

You can use an implement like this, try using row methods in order to divide items inside the row.

Comment: Thanks iShriyansh.... i have used your approach along with Adnan's approach it's working fine.....!! thanks for your help. Do you know how can i get "x" in front of the frequency and index values

Answer (score 0):

i hope it little help

```
class DemoWork extends StatefulWidget {
  const DemoWork({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DemoWork> createState() => _DemoWorkState();
}

class _DemoWorkState extends State<DemoWork> {

  List product=[
    {'product':'pencil', 'frequency': 10}, {'product':'pen','frequency':24}, {'product':'notebook','frequency':12}, {'product':'markers','frequency':2}, {'product':'erasers','frequency':21}
  ];
Iterable<dynamic>? data;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    product.sort((a, b) {
      return a['frequency'].compareTo(b['frequency']);
    });
   //output is {product: pen, frequency: 24}, {product: erasers, frequency: 21}, {product: notebook, frequency: 12}, {product: pencil, frequency: 10}, {product: markers, frequency: 2}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          reverse: true,// because list show low to high so reverse use to show high to low value and shrink wrap adjust its size use as you want to show and adjust it 
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListTile(
          leading:Text(index.toString()) ,
          title: Text(product[index]['product']),
          trailing: Text(product[index]['frequency'].toString()),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Adnan for your response.
is it possible that I can show the single item in a card and iterate the same card with a different product?

Comment: set parent of listtle to card so every item came with card , if answer solve problem kindly upvote for this

Comment: have you check it

Comment: it's working... now let me wrap it inside the card then will check the output

Comment: you can add serial number as like index which is Text(indeValue[index]) etc... which remain static, so create list List indexValue =[1,2,3,4,5]; and pass it

Comment: Thanks, Adnan its working fine....only problem i can see is that if the reverse is set to true scroll direction is also revered and Serial number too. Is there any way that I can reverse the product but the serial number should remain irreversible ( should start from 1 to product length).  and also scroll direction should be from top to bottom ......thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks it working fine...instead of sorting a to b i reversed the sorting order and i am getting the required result thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

You can counting time user buying stuffs and use it to sort the list. Of course u need to build your widget for yourself, i will only suggest the logic.

Example

```dart
void main() {
  var stuffs = ['ball', 'pen', 'pencil', 'glass']; // your stuff here
  var history = ['pencil', 'pencil', 'glass', 'pen', 'glass', 'pencil']; // your buy history here, you can add more if you want
  
  print('stuff will dispaly in order: $stuffs');
  
  stuffs.sort((a,b) => history.timesOf(b).compareTo(history.timesOf(a))); // Function that sort the list by 'buy times' of user store in `history` variable
  print('stuff will dispaly in order when using history: $stuffs');
  
}

extension HistoryCheck on List<String> {
  int timesOf(String name) => where((_) => _ == name).length;
}

// ===== Result =====
stuff will dispaly in order: [ball, pen, pencil, glass]
stuff will dispaly in order when using history: [pencil, glass, pen, ball]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the following product model and list of products:

```dart
// Product Model
class Product {
  final int serialNo;
  final String name;
  final int frequency;

  const Product(this.serialNo, this.name, this.frequency);
}

// List of products
List<Product> data = [
  Product(1, 'Pencil', 35),
  Product(2, 'Pen', 30),
  Product(3, 'Notebook', 25),
];
```

Just before showing this list of products in a list view, you can sort it based on the frequency as shown below:

```dart
data.sort((a, b) => b.frequency.compareTo(a.frequency));
```